# How to insert new line breaks using form_for with collection_check_boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, form-for

I use the following form_for at one point in my code to display a series of topics for users to select from.

```
 <%= form_for @user do |f| %> 
 <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:topic_ids, Topic.all.sample(50).each, :id, :topic_name) %> 
 <%= f.submit %>
 <% end %>
```

When it renders on the page, the boxes are all one-after-the-other. How can I separate them so that there is one check box per line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from [reference here](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes) 
It is possibly to customize the way the elements will be shown by giving a block to the method as sample below from your code above

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %> 
 <%= f.collection_check_boxes :topic_ids, Topic.all.sample(50).each, :id, :topic_name do |b| %> 
   <%= b.label(class: "check_box") do %>
     <%= b.check_box(class: "check_box") %>
     <%= b.object.topic_name %></br>
   <% end %>
 <% end %> 
 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: it is better to reference to [actual docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes)

Comment: Thanks! @widjajayd

Answer (score 2):

You may of course render HTML inside the block:

```
   <%= form_for @user do |f| %> 
      <%= f.collection_check_boxes :topic_ids, Topic.all.sample(50).each, :id, : topic_name do |b| %>
      <div  class="my-checkbox-wrapper">
        <%= b.label(class: "foo") do %>
          <%= b.object.topic_name %>
          <%= b.check_box(class: "bar") ></br>
       <%end%>
       <%= f.submit %>
    <%end%>
```

You can have a look at this [example](https://makandracards.com/makandra/32147-rails-4-introduced-collection_check_boxes)

Answer (score 0):

It is very broad question. In short, using CSS.

For example using [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#checkboxes-and-radios):

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
<div class="form-check">
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :topic_ids, Topic.all.sample(50).each, :id, :topic_name, class: 'form-check-input' %>
</div>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```